# Iterate JSON list and wrap each object of list with span tag

Tags: jquery, json

data.MaritalStatuses contains multiple values of marital statuses and I want them to wrap span tag on each value of marital status and append them in the td#maritalStatuses. In this case it is appending the values without wrapping them in span tags. How can I improve this ?

```
table += '<tr><td id="maritalStatuses">Marital Status</td><td>' + $.each(data.MaritalStatuses, function (index, value) {
  items.push('<span class="tags">' + value + '</span>');
}); $("#maritalStatuses").append(items); + '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: your code looks weird... :)...

Comment: just consider td and data.MaritalStatuses
I just want this:
<td><span>MaritalStatus1</span><span>MaritalStatus2</span><span>MaritalStatus3</span>.....</td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to create the status list array and then [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create a string out of it

```
table += '<tr><td id="maritalStatuses">Marital Status</td><td>';
if (data.MaritalStatuses.length) {
    table += $.map(data.MaritalStatuses, function (value) {
        return '<span class="tags">' + value + '</span>';
    }).join('')
} else {
    table += 'None';
}
table += '</td></tr>';
$("#maritalStatuses").append(table);
```

Comment: How to I check if length of data.MaritalStatuses should be greater than zero ?

Comment: @AliShahzad if the length is 0 then what do you want to do... don't display the `tr`?

Comment: if length is zero I want to display "None" in td instead of values

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

Html...

```
<table border="1">
    <tr id="maritalStatuses">
        <td >Marital Status</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery...

```
$(window).load(function(){
var data = {MaritalStatuses:['married','single','married']},
    mStatus = '';

$.each(data.MaritalStatuses, function (index, value) {
  mStatus += '<span class="tags">dd' + value + '</span>';
}); 

$("#maritalStatuses").append('<td>'+mStatus+'</td>');        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming `data.MaritalStatuses` is an `Array`, you would be better off using `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.join` instead of `$.each`

```
table += '<tr><td id="maritalStatuses">Marital Status</td><td>' +
    data.MaritalStatuses.map(function (index, value) {
        return '<span class="tags">' + value + '</span>';
    }).join('') +
    '</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var textvalues='';
$.each(data.MaritalStatuses, function (index, value) {
  textvalues+='<span class="tags">' + value + '</span>';
});
$("#maritalStatuses").append(textvalues)
```